# Docking Custom Task Panes

Tags: .net, excel, vsto, customtaskpane

I have developed two custom task pane addins to be used in Excel 2007. I set one to DockPosition = Left and the other to DockPosition = Top. This puts the Top pane all the way across the top, with the Left pane under it.

Is there a way to force the Left pane so that it goes all the way to the top, which would move the Top pane over (more specifically, it'd move directly over the Spreadsheet area, which is more functional for the purpose of this application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 99% certain the answer is no. I've looked and was not able to find a way to control this.